# How to return python dictionary to use in other function?

Tags: python, return, yield

In this function I'm reading from a .txt file, and store the values in a dictionary. I want to be able to pass this dictionary to another function, to do further calculations and sorting.

I can manage to print all rows from the .txt file, but that's it.

Return breaks the loop and only gives the first row.

Global variables and nested functions are bad form.

Have tried to use yield (for the first time), but that only prints "generator object get_all_client_id at 0x03369A20"

```
file_with_client_info = open("C:\\Users\\clients.txt", "r")

def get_all_client_id():
    client_details = {}

     for line in file_with_client_info:
        element = line.split(",")
        while element:
            client_details['client_id'] = element[0]
            client_details['coordinates'] = {}
            client_details['coordinates']['lat'] = element[1]
            client_details['coordinates']['long'] = element[2]
            break

        print(client_details)
```

Comment: You overwrite your dictionary each time through the loop, so what are you trying to accomplish? Do you want a list of dictionaries?  It seems to me that the keys in your dictionary should be each `client_id`, and the value is a dictionary containing those other attributes.

Comment: It only returns the first line from the -txt file

Comment: I want a dictionary, with the format like so: {'client_id': 'id: 8914ba03', 'coordinates': {'lat': ' lat: 51.47100685', 'long': ' long:16.29731236'}}

It doesn't seem to me that I overwrite it, since I can manage to print out the whole thing? But I won't say for sure that's the case. The loop principle with assigning key and values I think is working... I just want to be able to use the dictionary in another function.

Comment: You print it, then you overwrite it your next time through the loop.  You probably want to just append to a list And return that at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few errors in you code.

1. Use a `return` statement to output the dictionary.
2. The *while-loop* does not loop as you are breaking on the first iteration. Use an *if-statement* to check if the line is empty instead.
3. The last entries in the `client_details` dict are overwritten on each iteration. Create a new entry instead, probably using the `client_id` as key.
4. It is recommended you use a `with` context manager to open your file.
5. It is preferable to provide the name of your file to your function and let it open it instead of having a globally opened file.

Here is a fixed version of your code.

```
def get_all_client_id(file):
    client_details = {}

    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            element = line.strip().split(',')
            if element:
                client_id, lat, long, *more = element
                client_details[client_id] = {'lat': lat, 'long': long}

    return client_details

clients_dict = get_all_client_id("C:\\Users\\clients.txt")
```

Comment: `if line` will always be true, because `line` will at least be `'\n'` (or else the iterator would have stopped). You want `element = line.split(",")` then `if element` (which *may* be empty)

Comment: Thank you so much Oliver, much appreciated!